# Scrapy: Grabbing information AFTER an end tag nested in a data cell

Tags: python, html, scrapy

I want to grab a specific link.  My issue is that that link is identified within a cell without a specific tag.  For example:

```
<td class="tableText" style="padding-left: 10px;">
      <a href="/link">John</a>;&nbsp; 
      <a href="/link">Jacob</a>;&nbsp;  (Primary) <br/>
      <a href="/link">Jingle</a>;&nbsp; 
      <a href="/link">Bud</a>;&nbsp; 
</td>
```

Basically, I only want to scrape the link labeled "Jacob", identified through the text ("Primary") following it. In this case, my code so far looks like this:

```
item['stuff'] = response.xpath('//div[@id = "mainBody"]/table/tr/td/a/text()').extract()
```

In this case, I want scrapy to get a**[2]**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this work using the `following-sibling` axis:

```
>>> sel.xpath('//a[contains(following-sibling::text(), "Primary")]')
[<Selector xpath='//a[contains(following-sibling::text(), "Primary")]' data='<a href="/link">Jacob</a>'>]
```